# in SQL Server specifically, is it better to use a money column or a decimal column for currency values ?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

For the currency values, I am doing all the calculations in the business layer of ASP.net website so is there even a need to store in sql server as a money column ?

Comment: yes, i agree duplicate post. Money datatype is pure garbage, i like that. will use decimal. Will await moderator action on this duplication question i posted.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you're doing with it.  I would only use currency if I was dealing with multiple types of currencies (dollars and pesos) such as for a table of currency exchange rates.  Decimal has better precision and is more portable, but you need to know your units.